# How to get an object with non-primitive parameters from Database.SqlQuery?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Could you please advise what I should do in the question described below?

I have a class "Car" that is mapped with database table (Using EF Code First) and **it has only primitive object parameters**.

Also I have a second class "User" that is mapped with my database table too and this class has also object parameter Car.

Could you please tell me, how I can get the first object from DB, used to the following code EF?

```
DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<User>("dbo.GetFirstUser")
```

My function `dbo.GetFirstUser`:

```
SELECT UserID, FirstName, SecondName, CarID FROM dbo.User
```

When I try to get it, my query returns object only with primitive parameters, **object Car is always null**.

I will be thankful for your advice.

Thanks.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace TestTimerConsole
{
    [Table("Car", Schema = "usr")]
    class Car
    {
        [Key]
        public int CarID    { get; private set; }
        public string Name  { get; private set; }
    }
}

using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace TestTimerConsole
{
    [Table("User", Schema = "usr")]
    class User
    {
        [Key]
        public int UserID           { get; private set; }
        public string FirstName     { get; private set; }
        public string SecondName    { get; private set; }
        [ForeignKey("Car")]
        public int CarID            { get; private set; }
        public Car Car              { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add your dbo.GetFirstUser ?

Comment: @Munzer `SELECT UserID, FirstName, SecondName, CarID FROM dbo.User`

Comment: try adding inner join  
`SELECT UserID, FirstName, SecondName, CarID FROM dbo.User inner join Car on Car.ID = User.CarID`

Comment: What do you mean _'object car is always null'_ your select statement only returns the `CarId` not the car object. You will need to select the `Car` object if you want to access its properties.

Comment: @Scrobi Sorry, But how I can get Car if it is only a property my instance User? Using EF (Code First) I can get first instance User used to ContextDb, but is it possible to return using stored procedure?

Comment: You can use the `CarId` to select the `Car` that you want. 
Can you please add you `User` and `Car` code.

Comment: @Scrobi Done. You can check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently only selecting the `CarId`. You will need to select the `Car` object from the database. There are several ways you can do this.

#### Examples

```
using (var context = new DbContext())
{
    var query = from u in context.Users
                join c in context.Car on u.CarId equals c.CarId
                select new User 
                {
                    UserId = u.UserId,
                    FirstName = u.FirstName,
                    LastName = u.LastName,
                    Car = new Car()
                    { CarId = c.CarId, Name = c.Name } 
                }
}
```

After selecting the `User` using your stored procedure select the `Car`

```
User user = DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<User>("dbo.GetFirstUser");
Car car = DbContext.User.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CarId == user.CarId); //or create a stored proc if you want.
```

I think you could even updated the stored procedure to return everything.
You will have to make sure the properties map correctly though.

So change the the stored procedure to something like this:

```
SELECT UserID, FirstName, SecondName, CarID, c.Name as [Car.Name]
FROM dbo.User u
INNER JOIN dbo.Car c on u.CarId = c.CarId
```

Comment: I have done it, but my code still not work, could you please give the cue why?
I have pushed my "project" on GitHub. It contains Db model and sample MVC project. https://github.com/ZziM/MvcModelBind

Comment: Which did you try and what do you mean by `not work` does it fail to build or just not select the car details.